# Accelerated computing - which library to choose

Tags: c++, c, hpc

I want to learn something about High Performance Computing as such and currently before me stands the topic of accelerated computing (like GPU computing).

I would like to ask you which technology is currently commonly used and therefore most worth learning. Technologies I know, that exist currently are:

- CUDA - NVIDIA only
- OpenCL - Should work well for any device, that can accelerate computing
- AMP - Microsoft technology (what is very discouraging), but has great API
- Vulkan - new library from Khronos, which is very complex, yet very good in performance

and that's it if it's about my knowledge about what is currently available.

Best would be if there exists some library like AMP, which could be fully open and available for linux also.

If not, then I even would be happy about CUDA, but I do not know if companies often use AMD GPUs, because if yes, then I would like to not waste time on learning something, what may become useless.

PS. both C and C++ APIs are fine for me

So what's your experience with this topic?

Answer (score 1):

To add to your list, you could also consider [OpenACC](http://www.openacc.org/). They have nice examples on their site. It will accelerate for both CPUs and GPUs

> The OpenACC Application Program Interface describes a collection of compiler directives to specify loops and regions of code in standard C, C++ and Fortran to be offloaded from a host CPU to an attached accelerator. OpenACC is designed for portability across operating systems, host CPUs, and a wide range of accelerators, including APUs, GPUs, and many-core coprocessors.
>
> The directives and programming model defined in the OpenACC API document allow programmers to create high-level host+accelerator programs without the need to explicitly initialize the accelerator, manage data or program transfers between the host and accelerator, or initiate accelerator startup and shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Vulkan is rather a graphics API like OpenGL than a compute API like OpenCL (which generally does not mean that it is impossible to do computational tasks, just harder). Although nowadays there is also a project called [Vulkan Kompute](https://github.com/KomputeProject/kompute). If you want your code to run on mobile devices, it might be worth a try. I have not seen it used in the HPC context though.

The successor to OpenCL is called [SYCL](https://www.khronos.org/sycl/). This is what Intel is implementing through their [oneAPI/DPC++](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/data-parallel-c-plus-plus.html) (Data Parallel C++) language which also targets Nvidia and AMD GPUs.

With [ROCm/HIP](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Programming_Guides/Programming-Guides.html) (Heterogeneous-Computing Interface for Portability), AMD have created their own rival to CUDA which can be used on AMD and Nvidia GPUs.

OpenMP offloading or OpenACC are options, but only for very simple workloads/algorithms. As there is very little manual optimization that can be done for these compiler-assisted models, their performance is often significantly worse but it could improve with newer compiler versions.

There are also some projects like [Kokkos](https://kokkos.github.io/kokkos-core-wiki/#), [Raja](https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/raja-managing-application-portability-next-generation-platforms) and [Alpaka](https://alpaka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to abstract away all the platform-specific details.

There is a nice (and hopefully updated) overview table about compatibility between most of these programming models and vendors Nvidia, AMD and Intel in the [gpu-lang-compat](https://github.com/AndiH/gpu-lang-compat) repository. There are also lots of publications comparing performance, but as most of these frameworks are under active development, the benchmark results can change rapidly and I decided not to write too much about performance to avoid for this answer to age like fine milk.

CUDA as the oldest, most used and most mature model might still be the best in terms of the amount of resources and help that you can find on the internet. Most ideas about parallel programming and performance that are important in CUDA can be directly applied to other models/languages, so one should not be too concerned about it being a walled garden even though this is true as well.

The newer models like SYCL might have learned from early mistakes in CUDA that can still be present to avoid breaking old applications. As a C++ developer, one of the most annoying things about using CUDA are the C-style runtime APIs (some of this will hopefully be fixed through the [libcudac++](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libcudacxx) standard library they are developing).